# Python and pip versions are different and potentially causing problem

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pytorch, conda

I have both 3.6 and 3.8 python versions installed in my drive and I am using Anaconda for virtual environment with Python 3.6. When I say in cmd prompt:

```
  >python -V
Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

However when I look for pip versions it shows

```
  >pip3 -V
pip 20.1.1 from c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

I'm thinking this the cause of the problem when I use pip install -e . while my virtual environment is active:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1 (from spinup==0.2.0) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.1 (from spinup==0.2.0)
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: "
I have both 3.6 and 3.8 python versions installed in my drive and I am using Anaconda for virtual environment with Python 3.6" -> WHY if you are already using anacondo to create and manage virtual environments did you install a seperate python instead of creating a conda environment which would be much less confusing for you

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- https://snarky.ca/a-quick-and-dirty-guide-on-how-to-install-packages-for-python/

Comment: Because Anaconda doesn't support stable python 3.8  right now. Therefore I had to download Python 3.8 from outside of the anaconda.

Comment: Where are you getting that info from? python 3.8 is available from the default channels

Comment: @FlyingTeller It was the case 1 month ago, It wasnt allowing you to update your "base" environment to 3.8. Let me try again

Comment: you mean the base env that has all the pre-installed anaconda stuff installed into it?

Comment: Yes the base env, Why it doesnt allow me to install python 3.8 in that, I dont know.

Comment: It's not that python is incompatible or unstable, but with all the packages that anaconda has pre-installed, it cannot upgrade the python version because some of these packages are not compatible with the newer python version. If you don't need all that stuff anyway (which I assume, since you did a seperate python install which has none of the anaconda pre-installs), I would suggest to remove anaconda and install miniconda or simply create a venv with `conda create -n py38 python=3.8`

Comment: Oh thank you for that solves the confusion between Python versions. I deleted any other package then Anaconda and now pip and python synced. However didnt solve my problem for installing torch. But thank you @FlyingTeller

Comment: Try to follow the suggestions [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), esspecially, use `conda install` instead of pip

Comment: Conda doesn't alias `pip`. Whenever Conda installs `pip` it will always be `pip`, never `pip3` or `pip2`. Those latter ones will always resolve to other stuff on the PATH, which ideally you should take off PATH if possible.

Comment: By default, pip3.exe located in your python 3.8. When you use pip in conda env, it will use pip.exe of conda env. If you want to install package for python 3.8, you should exit from all env and try to use pip3. At the same time, you should delete all path  env vars for anaconda python. It's useless and make too much confusing.

Comment: Also many packages are not supported by conda therefore I need pip sometimes, thats an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @FlyingTeller suggests removing any seperate python version then Anaconda solve the confusion between pip and python. However didn't solve the actual problem. I will close this question and open another one, thanks.