# Python Running .py File with my Python Anaconda Version

Tags: python

I think I am close to solving my issues but need a little help.

Computer: Mac

My situation: wrote a script in Jupyter Notebooks (.ipynb) and I wanted to run it from IDLE. So I downloaded the .ipynb as a .py file. When I open up the file it opens in Idle and when I go to run the file it says I do not have the module/packages installed.

At the top of the .py file it put `#!/usr/bin/env python`

When I run `which python` in my terminal I get `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`.

So I am thinking IDLE is running the script through a different environment of python. **How do I change it so IDLE will run the script through the python Anaconda also uses?**

Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming there's a reason you can't just run the script through anaconda prompt?

Comment: from which environment did you run the notebook? use that same environment to run the .py file also

Comment: I believe the notebook is running through the anaconda environment (/opt/anaconda3/bin/python) so how do I change the .py file to run through that environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you have more than one python in your OS. Just check the versions in prompt with --version. If you get different python version you need to delete one that you dont use. It is generally the other than anaconda one.

Comment: The version I have: Python 3.8.3 Which is the correct one that I believe anaconda is running on. I think there might be another version installed but cant seem to find it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891021/python-and-pip-versions-are-different-and-potentially-causing-problem Maybe this question helps you.